# Why boost::program_options::bool_switch is not behaving like I expect?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-program-options

Code below uses `po::bool_switch(&flag)` in hope of automatically assigning the correct value to `flag`.

My compile command is `clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lboost_program_options`

So I run the program with `./test -h` which shows no help message.

Why so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace
{
  namespace po = boost::program_options;
}

int main(int ac, char ** av)
{
  bool flag;

  po::options_description help("Help options");

  help.add_options()
    ( "help,h"
    , po::bool_switch(&flag)->default_value(false)
    , "produce this help message" );

  po::variables_map vm;

  po::parsed_options parsed
    = po::parse_command_line(ac,av,help);

  po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac,av,help),vm);

  if (flag)
  {
    std::cout << help;
  }
  po::notify(vm);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `notify` responsible for storing values into variables? Can you move if before `if (flag)` an see if it corrects the behaviour?

Comment: Yes, that was my fault. Thanks very much

Comment: I've made it an answer with links to the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `notify` after parsing and storing arguments. `store` just fills in internal data structures of `variables_map`. `notify` publishes them.

Your example is nearly exactly like the one in "*Getting started section*" in [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html).

And [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp523516944) they give a pretty bold warning not to forget it:

> Finally the call to the notify function runs the user-specified notify functions and stores the values into regular variables, if needed.
>
> **Warning:**
> Don't forget to call the notify function after you've stored all parsed values.

This should work:

```
po::variables_map vm;
po::parsed_options parsed
  = po::parse_command_line(ac,av,help);
po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac,av,help),vm);
po::notify(vm); // call after last store, and before accesing parsed variables

if (flag)
{
  std::cout << help;
}
```

Comment: I've found the reason why I've putted notify after `if (flag)`. Due to other options... If some other required option is not provided by the user, notify will throw. Even if `help`-flag is provided. That's an use case my example did not show X-/
But anyway, my example/question is solved by your answer, so I mark it.